# php eliminar arrays duplicados basados en dos valores

Tags: php

estoy intentando borrar un array repetido en mis resultados, el borrado lo hago en funcion del campo: publishedDate y del name, para que el mismo dia y con la misma persona no haya más de dos resultados. Para que no sea ducplicado.

**array de ejemplo, con menos campos**

```
^ array:3 [▼
  0 => array:16 [▼
    "name" => "Peter San"
    "publishedDate" => 1661378400
    "foto" = > "none"
  ]
  1 => array:16 [▼
    "name" => "Peter San"
    "publishedDate" => 1661378400
    "foto" = > "none"

  ]
  2 => array:16 [▼
    "name" => "Mike Tomas"
    "publishedDate" => 1661292000
    "foto" = > "none"

  ]
]
```

He intentado este codigo, pero solo lo borra basado en un campo, cuando necesito basarlo en dos campos.

**php**

```
        $ids = array_column($resultOfAthors, 'publishedDate');
        $ids = array_unique($ids);
        $resultOfAthors = array_filter($resultOfAthors, function ($key, $value) use ($ids) {
            return in_array($value, array_keys($ids));
        }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH);
```

**el resultado final tendría que ser:**

```
^ array:3 [▼
  0 => array:16 [▼
    "name" => "Peter San"
    "publishedDate" => 1661378400
    "foto" = > "none"

  ]
  2 => array:16 [▼
    "name" => "Mike Tomas"
    "publishedDate" => 1661292000
    "foto" = > "none"

  ]
]
```

¿alguna idea de recorrer el array y borrar cuando se repitan ambos campos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bueno yo he implementado esto:

```php
<?php
$arr = [
    ["name" => "Peter San","publishedDate" => 1661378400],
    ["name" => "Mike Tomas","publishedDate" => 1661292000],
    ["name" => "Peter San","publishedDate" => 1661378400],
];
$arr = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $arr)));
print_r($arr);
```

Output:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Utilizando [array_map](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-map.php), [array_unique](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-unique), [serialize](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.serialize) y [unserialize](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.unserialize)

te dejo la documentacion para que la estudies.

Comment: gracias por responder ! pero con el array que tengo he probado y no me funciona, ya que tiene mas campos :( y necesito basarme en que no se dupliquen esos dos valores,

Comment: pero es lo que has presentado en tu pregunta... si hay algo que no has agregado, no quiere decir que no funcione mi respuesta... si vez es el mismo ouput que colocaste o esperas...

Comment: puse " array de ejemplo, con menos campos " tenia que haber puesto mas campos de ejemplo , sorry !

Comment: pues que te puedo decir ... jajajajaja aui te damos lo que pides, basado en lo que nos muestres ...

Comment: Te recomendaria hacer nuevamente la pregunta en un nuevo post con todos los requerimientos que tengas y no dejes nada por fuera...