# PHP Limpiar Duplicados en arrays Multidimencional basados en solo dos llaves y sus dos valores

Tags: php

Estoy intentando borrar los arrays repetido en los resultados, el borrado lo hago en funcion del campo: `publishedDate` y del `name`, para que el mismo dia y con la misma persona no haya más de dos resultados. Para que no sea duplicado.

**array de ejemplo, con menos campos**

```
[
  [
    "name" => "Peter San",
    "publishedDate" => 1661378400,
    "foto" => "yes"
  ],
  [
    "name" => "Peter San",
    "publishedDate" => 1661378400,
    "foto" => "none"
  ],
  [
    "name" => "Mike Tomas",
    "publishedDate" => 1661292000,
    "foto" => "none"
  ]
]
```

He intentado este codigo, pero solo lo borra basado en un campo, cuando necesito basarlo en dos campos especificos (`publishedDate` y del `name`):

```php
        $ids = array_column($resultOfAthors, 'publishedDate');
        $ids = array_unique($ids);
        $resultOfAthors = array_filter($resultOfAthors, function ($key, $value) use ($ids) {
            return in_array($value, array_keys($ids));
        }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH);
```

**El resultado final esperado tendría que ser:**

```
[
  [
    "name" => "Peter San",
    "publishedDate" => 1661378400,
    "foto" => "yes"
  ],
  [
    "name" => "Mike Tomas",
    "publishedDate" => 1661292000,
    "foto" => "none"
  ]
]
```

En mi investigacion realice esta este post pero no tenia el alcance deseado: [php eliminar arrays duplicados basados en dos valores](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/553692/46896)

No se Limpiar Duplicados en arrays Multidimencional basados en solo dos Valores, ¿me pueden ayudar a encontrar o brindar el codigo que resuelve este problema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bueno aqui ya cambia el escenario un poco y se debe implementar otro metodo, yo haria lo siguiente:

```php
<?php
$arr = [
  [
    "name" => "Peter San",
    "publishedDate" => 1661378400,
    "foto" => "yes"
  ],
  [
    "name" => "Peter San",
    "publishedDate" => 1661378400,
    "foto" => "none"
  ],
  [
    "name" => "Mike Tomas",
    "publishedDate" => 1661292000,
    "foto" => "none"
  ]
];

function unique_by_keys($haystack=[],$needles=[]){
    foreach($haystack as $row){
        $key = implode('', array_intersect_key($row, array_flip($needles)));  // declarar clave única
        if(!isset($result[$key])){
            $result[$key]=$row;
        } // Guardar fila si no es duplicada
    }
    return array_values($result);
}

print_r(unique_by_keys($arr,["name","publishedDate"]));
```

***Output:***

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como podras ver en este caso implemento otros metodos de php, te dejo la documentacion para que puedas estudiarlos: [implode](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.implode.php), [array_intersect_key](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-intersect-key), [array_flip](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-flip), [isset](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.isset) y [array_values](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-values)

***Nota:*** este metodo es mucho más dinamico; ya que acepta que le indiques basado en que llavez quiere que se filtre el array.

Espero que esto si resuelva tu necesidad y alcance.

Comment: mil gracias! llevaba todo el día con esto! solucionado mil graciass!

Comment: pa eso estamos...

Comment: el método es eficiente pero tiene un problema, que la _clave_ generada con `implode` puede ser la misma para valores diferentes. por ejemplo si el primer elemento fuera `["name" => "Peter San1", "publishedDate" => 661378400, "foto" => "yes"]` tendría una clave idéntica al segundo a pesar de tener valores diferentes. podrías cambiarlo por `$key = serialize(array_intersect_key($row, array_flip($needles)));`.

Comment: podrias reproducir el escenario que sugieres haca: https://onlinephp.io/ y nos compartes el codigo bro.

Answer (score 0):

También existe otro método que voy creando.

guardo como string concatenando ambas columnas (name, publishedDate) en un array y luego verifico que no se encuentre el mismo string en el array.

```
$arr = [
  [
    "name" => "Peter San",
    "publishedDate" => 1661378400,
    "foto" => "yes"
  ],
  [
    "name" => "Peter San",
    "publishedDate" => 1661378400,
    "foto" => "none"
  ],
  [
    "name" => "Mike Tomas",
    "publishedDate" => 1661292000,
    "foto" => "none"
  ]
];

$check = [];
$result = array_filter($lista, function($el) use(&$check) {
    $fil = $el['name']."-".$el['publishedDate'];
    if (!in_array($fil, $check)) {
        $arr[] = $fil;
        return $el;
    }
});
```

ese mismo codigo me da como resultado:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(9) "Peter San"
    ["publishedDate"]=>
    int(1661378400)
    ["foto"]=>
    string(3) "yes"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(10) "Mike Tomas"
    ["publishedDate"]=>
    int(1661292000)
    ["foto"]=>
    string(4) "none"
  }
}
```

Funciones empleadas en la documentación de PHP: [array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-filter.php)
[in_array](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.in-array.php)

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).